# I want my images to be "likable" like Facebook and Instagram. But it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have an image which has two features:

1. It changes when the image is hovered on.
2. Images are "likable" and have a heart shaped icon.

When the heart is clicked, the image is liked and when it is clicked once again it is unliked.

These two features work fine separately, but when combined, liking feature doesn't work anymore.

```js
function show_large(element) {
  element.innerHTML =
    '<img src="2.JPG">\
    <div class="favorite-icon" onclick="switch_rs(this)">\
      <div class="far fa-heart"></div>\
    </div>';
  if (element.rs == "s") {
    element.innerHTML =
      '<img src="2.JPG">\
      <div class="favorite-icon" onclick="switch_rs(this)">\
        <div class="fas fa-heart"></div>\
      </div>';
  }
}

function show_normal(element) {
  element.innerHTML =
    '<img src="1.JPG">\
    <div class="favorite-icon" onclick="switch_rs(this)">\
      <div class="far fa-heart"></div>\
    </div>';
  if (element.rs == "s") {
    element.innerHTML =
      '<img src="1.JPG">\
      <div class="favorite-icon" onclick="switch_rs(this)">\
        <div class="fas fa-heart"></div>\
      </div>';
  }
}

function switch_rs(element) {
  if (element.parentElement.rs == "r") {
    element.parentElement.rs = "s";
    element.innerHTML = '<div class="fas fa-heart"></div>';
  } else if (element.parentElement.rs == "s") {
    element.parentElement.rs = "r";
    element.innerHTML = '<div class="far fa-heart"></div>';
  } else {
    element.parentElement.rs = "s";
    element.innerHTML = '<div class="fas fa-heart"></div>';
  }
}
```

```css
.favorite-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.width-20 {
  width: 20%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="width-20" onmouseenter="show_large(this)" onmouseout="show_normal(this)">
  <img src="1.JPG">
  <div class="favorite-icon" onclick="switch_rs(this)">
    <div class="far fa-heart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just show and hide stuff. Also mousing over other stuff triggers enter and leave

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Showing and hiding stuff is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: No. You remove and insert stuff. Use `element.classList.toggle("show",someTest)`  or `element.style.display= someTest? "block":"none"` -  what is .rs anyway? If an attribute, you need .getAttribute("rs")

Comment: @mplungjan I don't see why this is where problem rises. Can't we say my way is just another way to do it? I just want to make sure your alternative will solve the problem, before editing my code.

Comment: Well first use better methods where you can stop bubbling and have less flicker. I do not know where to start on your code